# Print review always display border in website html/css

Tags: html, css

I have problem. I am studying HTML + CSS. I wrote code like this:

htm file:

```css
#leftblock
{

    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: brown;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

#rightblock
{
    background-color: #A54739;
    height: 700px;
    width: 500px;
    left: 159px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
#rightblock #subrightblock
{
    height: 660px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color:bisque;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#menu
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;

}


#menu ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 110px;
}

#menu ul li
{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#menu ul li:hover
{
    background-color: #025780;
}

#menu ul li:first-child
{
    border-top: none;
}

a
{
 text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a
 {
     text-decoration: none;
     display:block;
     padding: 5px;
     color: #000;
     font-size:15px;
     border:1px solid #FFF;
     text-align:center;

 }

#menu li
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: crimson;
    list-style: none;


}

#submenu
{
    text-align: center;
}
#submenu ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 110px;
}


#submenu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;

}



p {font-family: fantasy}

p {text-indent: 20px}


#spistresci
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #025780;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 10px solid crimson;
    padding: 10px;

}

p:first-letter
{
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #528011;
}


h1
{
    color: blueviolet;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}
h2
{
    color: aqua
}
h3
{
    color: darkgoldenrod
}
h4
{
    color: darkred
}
h5
{
    color: gray
}
h6
{
    color: darkseagreen
}
p {text-indent: 20px}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
{
    text-align: center;
}
table{
    border: 2px black;
    border-collapse: separate;

}

td {
    border-style: groove;
    background-color: burlywood;
}

span {
    background-color: teal;
}



th {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ol li ol li ol {
    list-style-type: lower-greek;
}
img.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;


}
img.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ćwiczenie 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wydruk.css" type="text/css" media="print" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="leftblock">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Strona Główna</a> </li>
            <li><a href="cw1.html">Ćwiczenie 1 </a> </li>
            <li><a href="cw2.html">Ćwiczenie 2 </a> </li>
            <li><a href="cw3.html">Ćwiczenie 3 </a> </li>
            <li><a href="cw4.html">Ćwiczenie 4 </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Strona Główna</a> </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ćwiczenie 1 </a> </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ćwiczenie 2 </a> </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ćwiczenie 3 </a> </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ćwiczenie 4 </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="rightblock">
    <div id="subrightblock">
        <h1>Formatowanie tekstu</h1>
        <h2>Formatowanie tekstu</h2>
        <h3>Formatowanie tekstu</h3>
        <h4>Formatowanie tekstu</h4>
        <h5>Formatowanie tekstu</h5>
        <h6>Formatowanie tekstu</h6>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dapibus lorem in felis sodales, sit amet sodales risus sagittis. Aenean vitae malesuada erat.
            Cras interdum nunc sit amet nunc cursus, quis convallis ligula tristique. Cras at gravida turpis. Nunc viverra neque in arcu ultrices semper. Vivamus in posuere velit.
            Maecenas lobortis tempor elit, non sagittis quam fringilla quis. Cras id hendrerit metus. Quisque sit amet scelerisque neque. Sed euismod vestibulum nisi, vel scelerisque urna aliquam in.
        </p>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

wydruk.css

```css
#leftblock
{
display: none;
}

#rightblock
{
 text-align: left;
}
#rightblock #subrightblock
{

}

#menu
{
    display: none;

}


body
{
    border: none;
}

#menu ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 110px;
}

#menu ul li
{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#menu ul li:hover
{
    background-color: #025780;
}

#menu ul li:first-child
{
    border-top: none;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-size:15px;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align:center;

}

#menu li
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: crimson;
    list-style: none;


}

#submenu
{
    text-align: center;
}
#submenu ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 110px;
}


#submenu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;

}







p:first-letter
{
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #528011;
}


h1
{
    color: blueviolet;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}
h2
{
    color: aqua
}
h3
{
    color: darkgoldenrod
}
h4
{
    color: darkred
}
h5
{
    color: gray
}
h6
{
    color: darkseagreen
}


h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
table{
    border: 2px black;
    border-collapse: separate;

}

td {
    border-style: groove;
    background-color: burlywood;
}

span {
    background-color: teal;
}



th {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ol li ol li ol {
    list-style-type: lower-greek;
}
img.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;


}
img.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;

}
```

The problem is that every time I look on print review, I always get text with a border on right side of A4 paper. The problem is that I don't have a border anywhere else in wydruk.css so I don't know why this border is being created.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you show an image example of where the border is located? I am assuming english may or may not be your first language, so it's a little hard for me to follow where "print review" is located.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the CSS code in your first snippet is from "style.css", and that you want "wydruk.css" to completely override it when printing.

All you have to do is add `media="screen"` to the first stylesheet link, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
```